# To completely remove i3 WN ans desktop environment from minimal debian?

Tags: debian, i3

I have been facing the same issues like this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/636250/how-to-compleately-remove-the-i3-desktop-enviroment-from-ubuntu#_=_
but with Debian. I have removed i3 files but still it shows up in initial sign-in window when login.
How can i remove i3 WM from debian completely? (I already have GNOME)

I have used following simple commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove i3
sudo apt-get purge i3 
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Update*

I further used

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep desktop
```

to look at all the desktop word containing environments and confirmed that i3 was not there. Then why am I seeing i3 in login window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i3 is an X11 window manager and not a desktop environment. It most certainly shows up in your display manager because there's a corresponding desktop entry for i3 in `/usr/share/xsessions/`.

You can [find the package](https://superuser.com/questions/10997/find-what-package-a-file-belongs-to-in-ubuntu-debian) providing the file via `dpkg -S /usr/share/xsessions/i3.desktop`

You can also check the dependencies of the [i3](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/i3) meta-package (`apt-cache show i3`), to find the name of the most likely package.

In your case it should be the package **i3-wm**. Uninstall the package, restart your display manager and i3 should not be listed anymore.

Comment: It shows i3 package is not installed. I think there are some config files left. But anyways how do I remove all files of i3 and X11?

Comment: i3-wm is the name of a different package than i3. i3 is a meta-package with dependencies to other packages (required: i3-wm, recommended: dunst, i3lock, i3status, suckless-tools).
[i3-wm](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/i3-wm) is the package containing the actual files (binaries, configuration and documentation) of the i3 window manager, which is the package that needs to be removed.

You can uninstall this package with `sudo apt-get purge i3-wm`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's late but I was able to remove all packages and it didn't show i3 in sign-in window anymore.